# How do I prevent double valueChanged events when I press the arrows in a QSpinbox?

Tags: qt, pyqt5

Could be a either a Qt bug, or a bug in my app, I am hoping someone can help me diagnose this.

I am building a PyQt5 application with an interface built using qtdesigner and pyuic5.

I have to `QSpinBox` widgets in my window, which I connect to two methods like this:

```
self.img1IndexBox.valueChanged.connect(self.changeImage1)
self.img2IndexBox.valueChanged.connect(self.changeImage2)
```

Everything seems to work fine in the application, except for one thing: If I scroll the mouse over the spinbox, I can make it increment the value. If I change the value with text, all works fine. If I use keyboard arrows on the spinbox, it works fine. But if I click on either the up or down arrows from the spinbox, I get get two `changeValue` events, a double increment. Like I clicked twice. In fact, it even looks from the animation that it is creating an event for the downpress, and another when the button goes back up.

Could this be just a library bug, or what could be causing this in my program? How could I debug this?

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to prevent that double thing by setting spinbox enable to false.
then make it enable to true after processing large data.

Upon clicking the arrow up/down 
on_valuechanged
ui->spinbox->setEnabled(false);

then set to true before the function on_valuechanged ends. 
ui->spinbox->setEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is the event is triggering a very long routine, this delays the "button release" event, and it is enough time to make the system think the user is actually holding the button, generating more events... But I would still be interested in learning what would be a good walk-around. Would there be a nice pyqt-onic way to start a thread for that method?

http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-43078.html

Comment: Most solutions involve something like creating a full QObject to handle that, but I am updating a drawing in matplotlib FigureCanvasQTAgg, that's what is taking so long. So it would be nice to figure out how to create a widget that can do that in a more natural way.

Comment: So the canvas actually has synchronous `draw()` and an async `draw_idle()` methods, using that is probably the way to go. I'm sorry to post a question and an answer like this, I hope putting the information together might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `valueChanged.connect` use `editingFinished.connect` it will make sure the function is called only after value is provided.

### PyQt

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDoubleSpinBox, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSpinBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    # def valueChanged(self, value):
    #     print(value)
    def valueChanged(self):
        print(f"Value changed new value is : {self.spinBox.value()}")

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 100)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setRange(0, 1000)
        # self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.spinBox.editingFinished.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### PySide

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QDoubleSpinBox, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSpinBox
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    # def valueChanged(self, value):
    #     print(value)
    def valueChanged(self):
        print(f"Value changed new value is : {self.spinBox.value()}")

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 100)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setRange(0, 1000)
        # self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.spinBox.editingFinished.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```